# MySQL syntax error at line 1 and backtick offering odd solution

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registration

This query

```
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']); // User's email.
$key = RandomString(128); // A random string of 128 characters.
$newTime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + 1800; // Expiration timer.
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO verification (
        email, 
        key, 
        time
    ) VALUES (
        '$email', 
        '$key', 
        $newTime
    )";
$errors = false;

$mysqli->autocommit(false);
foreach ($queries as $query) {
    if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
        $errors = true;
    }
}
```

is giving me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, time) VALUES ('example@domain.net', 'e1e4091197640bae0a4588b8666e87b6b' at line 1.

But the query above works, just by adding a few backticks (grave accent):

```
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO verification (
        `email`, 
        `key`, 
        `time`
    ) VALUES (
        '$email', 
        '$key', 
        $newTime
    )";
```

Can anyone explain how this change would fix the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`time` and `key` are reserved words. If you're going to use them for a column name, which is a bad idea, they requires backticks to escape them.

Comment: Wow, that was really fast. I had a feeling it would be something stupid like that. Thank you. :)

Comment: You're right about `key` but `time` can be used without backticks. Due to so many people using it for a column name, MySQL permits it.

Answer (score 4):

Backticks are needed in MySQL whenever the name of an identifier is a reserved word. In your case, `KEY` is a reserved word and will cause syntax errors unless you enclose it like that. It's normally a good idea to avoid creating names like that.

You can find a list of reserved words [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this--
You can not use key like that as it is a reserve keyword of mysql. use tild (`) around it so that it will take it as field.

```
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO verification (
        email, 
        `key`, 
        time
    ) VALUES (
        '$email', 
        '$key', 
        $newTime
    )";
```